# How to play music on multiple Ubuntu machines simultaneously?

Tags: sound, alsa, music, lan

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my Laptop. I want to play music on other Ubuntu laptops simultaneously including mine. All the laptops are connected via LAN.

If it is not possible for many laptops than any method for playing audio on more than one laptop would be very helpful.

Comment: You can try VLC player if you have GUI, because its have streaming features

Comment: @ShivSingh , VLC Streaming is very slow and laggy. If I can transfer files over Local Area Connection with 1Gbps speed then why can't i play a music simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [Icecast](http://icecast.org/). You'll be able to install the Icecast streaming server on one of the laptops, which should be able to broadcast on your local network to an open port. You'll need to configure a streaming server (icecast) and a source client (IceS), but then you'll be able to broadcast from that server and tune into the stream from each other device you want to play the same track.

It's been quite some time since I've used Icecast, so I unfortunately don't know if I can give you a great step-by-step configuration, but hopefully you'll might be able to get started with [their Basic Setup guide](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/basic-setup.html). It's not really a GUI process; it'll require manually creating and/or editing configuration files.